# How to access checkbox from datagrid template column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

Ok this has been asked many times but I just can't find the right solution. I have datagrid defined like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      Name="InputDocItemsDataGrid"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path= InputItems}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path= InputItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      SelectionChanged="InputDocItemsDataGrid_SelectionChanged"
      PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="InputDocItemsDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="cbxAll_Checked" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="cbxSingleRow" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="cbxSingleRow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Well I added only this template column here becouse it's the point of interest. So what I'm trying to manage is to access checkobx "cbxSingleRow" as it is outside of datagrid, so i would be able to do all the regular stuff with it like for example: cbxSingleRow.IsEnabled = false;

So how do I get that checkbox?

Comment: "all the regular stuff" is done via DATABINDING in WPF. not procedural code.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I just need to access that checkbox from codebehind like it is any other checkbox outside of datagrid? Is there any clear solution to get that effect?

Comment: `I just need to access that checkbox from codebehind` - what for? whatever you want to do, do it via DataBinding.

Comment: hi Stojdza,,,,i m facing same problem..u have solution about it?

Comment: @SANDEEP hay there! Yes I have solved it by using visual tree helper class as Rohit described in his answer but just a little bit different. Also there is another approach to access controls inside a DataGrid via databinding and using of RelativeSource property. If you need some more info let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that with the help of `VisualTreeHelper` class.

Move this method in some utility class so that can be reused.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj,
                                         string name) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
       {
          DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
          if (child != null && child is T &&
                (child as FrameworkElement).Name.Equals(name))
          {
             yield return (T)child;
          }

          foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child, name))
          {
             yield return childOfChild;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (CheckBox checkBox in UtilityFunctions.
             FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(InputDocItemsDataGrid, "cbxSingleRow"))
{           
   checkBox.IsChecked = true;
}
```